# How do I return true/false based on the function to HTML and set the disabled value?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Javascript function to return true/false.

```
$scope.createDisabled = false;      
function isEnabled() {
                    if ($scope.node.activationStatus == "Y") {
                        $scope.createDisabled = true;
                    } 
                    else {
                        $scope.createDisabled = false;
                    }
                }
```

HTML

```
<stx-action-create disabled="createDisabled"></stx-action-create>
```

The result that was returned to the view was false and it did not change according to the condition.

Comment: Please add more code, where you called "function isEnabled()"

Comment: You can't use interpolation with the disabled attribute, look here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled, use that directive instead.

Comment: Are you looking for something like this - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/VXxRKX , AngularJS interpolation expression is lost for boolean attributes like disabled , so it will be disabled always, use ng-disabled as per official angular documentation- https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/interpolation

Answer (score 0):

There can be three cases:

1. $scope object does not apply changes in view if you isEnabled function being trigger by a non angular method.
2. For some reason your angular digest cycle not being run
3. Workaround in `stx-action-center` disabled attribute just call the `isEnabled` function and return the Boolean from the function(skip $scope)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not invoking the function you created.

**Please make changes**

```
to your html as shown below. 
<stx-action-create disabled="isEnabled()"></stx-action-create>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Changes in JavaScript**

```
$scope.createDisabled = false; // Not sure if this is necessary
$scope.isEnabled = function () { // Make the method available on $scope
    return ($scope.node.activationStatus == "Y");
}
```

**Changes in HTML**

```
<stx-action-create disabled="isEnabled()"></stx-action-create>
```

This should solve the problem.

Comment: The changes did not make any changes and it remained the same as it was before even after making the method available on $scope. I also found the digest cycle is not working.

Comment: The basic assumption in my answer is that the attribute "disabled" within the directive "stxActionCreate" is defined and taken care of. If not so, then, it is required to be changed to ng-disabled - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled